# Interactive mode does not receive options the right way

Tags: command-line-interface, angular7

My Angular CLI does not receive options by the right way.
For example `--interactive=false` does not ask any question.

My environment:

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.2
Node: 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.2
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.2
@schematics/angular          7.2.2
@schematics/update           0.12.2
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.2
```

Please help.

Comment: You've putted interactive at false. So it's not interactive. Sorry buddy.

Comment: ng n angtest --interactive=true and ng new without options I get the same result - no questions asked.